# Save bitmap to internal storage and then choose it with picker

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to save bitmap to gallery to open it again from ImagePicker intent.

The problem is - if I'm saving it on external storage, it will not work on devices without it, and when I'm writing it on internal storage - it won't shown in gallery, so i can not pick that image.

Tried so many ways of resolving it, but no success this far.

I mean, is it possible to save bitmap in internal storage and open it from activity, which called to choose image from gallery?

edit: added code

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String filename){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,filename + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

With that procedure it's seems like saving bitmap is ok, but i can't find that file in gallery.

Comment: Share your code tried?